# Nodejs application to wait till all URLs are scraped by python script in the backend

Tags: python, node.js, web-scraping

My Nodejs application has below as input

1. csv file of URLs
2. keywords to search
3. checkbox option to search for all links even getting one link having keywords

output
1)csv file (code not working)

The python code returns a csv string, i want the user to have some prompt to download the csv file, but the execution of the python script is taking more time and thus it results in below message as in pic.
[image]

please see my code file
1)app.js
2)webextraction.py

file `app.js`

```
/* csv to json */
const express = require("express"),
  app = express(),
  upload = require("express-fileupload"),
  csvtojson = require("csvtojson");

var http = require('http');
var path = require("path");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var helmet = require('helmet');
var rateLimit = require("express-rate-limit");

let csvData = "test";
app.use(upload());

var server = http.createServer(app);

const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000, // 15 minutes
  max: 100 // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(limiter);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() { 
    console.log('server running on port 3000'); 
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

// Will remove all falsy values: undefined, null, 0, false, NaN and "" (empty string)
function cleanArray(actual) {
  var newArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < actual.length; i++) {
    if (actual[i]) {
      newArray.push(actual[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}

function get_array_string(inp){
  var str = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
    str = str + " " + inp[i]
  }
  return str.trim()
}

const chunks = [];

// form submit request
app.post('/formsubmit', function(req, res){

    // console.log("Form submit request")
    csvData = req.files.csvfile.data.toString('utf8');
    filteredArray = cleanArray(csvData.split(/\r?\n/))
    csvData = get_array_string(filteredArray)

    console.log("URL list received: "+csvData)
    console.log("Search keywords: "+req.body.keywords)
    console.log("Full search: "+req.body.full_search)

    // Send request to python script
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var process = spawn('python', ["./WebExtraction.py", csvData, req.body.keywords, req.body.full_search])

    dataString = "";

    process.stdout.on('data', function(data){
      dataString = dataString + data.toString()

      console.log(dataString)

    });

    
    process.stdout.on('end', function(){

      // res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=testing.csv');
      // res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
      // res.status(200).send(dataString);

    });
    
    process.stdin.end();

});
```

Following is a part of the python script code which sends csv string the nodejs application.

```
    ######################################################################################
    ## CREATING THE FINAL DATA FRAME FOR COLLECTING the extracted urls
    ######################################################################################
    colList = ['Found urls', 'Not found urls','Error urls']
    dframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = colList, dtype = str)

    maxlen = get_max_of_list(found_results_A, found_keywords_list_changed, notfound_results, error_urls)

    found_results_A = append_space(found_results_A, maxlen)
    notfound_results = append_space(notfound_results, maxlen)
    error_urls = append_space(error_urls, maxlen)
    found_keywords_list_changed = append_space(found_keywords_list_changed, maxlen)

    if(len(found_results_A) == maxlen and len(notfound_results) == maxlen and len(error_urls) == maxlen and len(found_keywords_list_changed) == maxlen):    
        dframe['Found urls'] = found_results_A
        dframe['keywords'] = found_keywords_list_changed
        dframe['Not found urls'] = notfound_results
        dframe['Error urls'] = error_urls

    try:    
        dframe = dframe.sort_values(by=["Found urls"], ascending=False)
        data = dframe.dropna(axis=0, how='all', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
        export_csv = dframe.to_csv(encoding = 'ASCII', index = None, header = True)
        # print(create_json(export_csv))
        print(export_csv)
    except Exception as err:
        print('Exception occurred, Error on line {}'.format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno), type(err).__name__, err)
        print(err)
```

My command prompt output
[image: output]

Comment: anyone here to answer this question

Comment: I believe this is the same as the other question I just answered - you need to end the request in some way. You commented out res.status(200).send(). That's the line that tells express/node to end the request. If you don't end it, your browser will keep waiting for data until a timeout occurs.